# White page with Famo.us/Angular starter kit on Cordova app

Tags: cordova, famous-angular

I'm trying to do Famo.us/Angular app and create Android app with Cordova.
I'm using starter kit (http://famo.us/integrations/angular/#/download) and made just some minor changes to build with grunt:

To build app, i do next commands :
 - bower install
 - cordovacli build
 - cordovacli run

Build is done, and everything seems to work fine. But when app is launched on android device, i have a white page.
In logs i have this :

```
D/CordovaLog( 8978): file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/famous/famous-global.js: Line 434 : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'requestAnimationFrame'

E/Web Console( 8978): Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'requestAnimationFrame':434

D/CordovaLog( 8978): file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js: Line 3906 : Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module integrationApp due to:

D/CordovaLog( 8978): Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module famous.angular due to:

D/CordovaLog( 8978): ReferenceError: famous is not defined

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/famous-angular/dist/famous-angular.js:21:28)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at invoke (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3966:17)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3977:23)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at provider (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3833:36)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at Object.provider (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3825:16)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3885:37

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at loadModules (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3872:5)

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3879:40

D/CordovaLog( 8978):     at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:18)

D/CordovaLog( 8978): http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=famous.angular&p1=ReferenceError%3A%20famous%20is%20not%20defined%0A%20%20%20%20at%20new%20%3Canonymous%3E%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Ffamous-angular%2Fdist%2Ffamous-angular.js%3A21%3A28)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20invoke%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3966%3A17)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.instantiate%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3977%3A23)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20provider%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3833%3A36)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.provider%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3825%3A16)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3885%3A37%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A325%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3872%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A3879%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(file%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A325%3A18)
```

If i take a look on index.html, famous is included and path is good :

```
<!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/famous/famous-global.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/famous-angular/dist/famous-angular.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
```

I feel that "famous-angular.js" do not find "famous" but it's included on "famous-global.js".

**PS :** if i build it in my web browser, it works fine.

Does any one have an idea? Please share.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? It looks like ```requestAnimationFrame``` is available only since Android 4.4 http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe

Comment: You are right ! I tested my app on Android 4.2 and i have these errors. Then i tested on Android 4.4 and everything is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @pasine help.

The source of the problem is the version of android.

'requestAnimationFrame' is only supported with android 4.4+ version.
Next errors arising from the first.

I don't have these errors on android 4.4.

Famo.us compatibility reminder :

- iOS: 4.3+
- Android: JellyBean+

**there are workarounds for this problem :**

- support "requestAnimationFrame" in android 4.4- with "raf.js" (https://github.com/ngryman/raf.js)
- set chromium as webview browser by default (4.0+ compatibility) using crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html#Migrate-using-command-line-tools)